# Delete statement with JDBC have no effect

Tags: sql, database, oracle, jdbc, command

I am using oracle 19c on windows platform.
username and password  is hr/hr

```
try{  
        //step1 load the driver class  
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

        //step2 create  the connection object  
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orclpdb","hr","hr");  


        //step3 create the statement object  
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  



    int deletedRows = stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM my_employee WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE '%man%'");
        if(deletedRows>0){
              System.out.println("Deleted Specific Row in the  table successfully...");
           }else{
             System.out.println("Not exist specific row that you select for delete");
          } 

        con.close();  

        }catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}
```

Not working. There is no error showing, no syntax error.
But output here is:
Not exist specific row that you select for delete

After using select * from my_employee:
Here is the table row (with no effect of delete statement):

```
EMPLOYEE_ID        FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 DEPARTMENT_ID      SALARY

 -----------     --------------------   ------------------------- -------------  ----------

 1                asaamansad           asdamansda                      12       21312
```

But same SQL command:

```
delete from my_employee where LAST_NAME LIKE '%man%';
```

This one works on command prompt or sql developer.
The above row got deleted when the same sql command used on command prompt.
Please solve this problem.

Comment: Disabled autocommit ? Add an explicit COMMIT to the code - although autocommit should be TRUE by default, but who knows - maybe there is an error in your version of the driver ? BTW: close also `stmt` in this code, there is a risk of resource leak.

Comment: Did you start a new transaction when querying the database? Otherwise you might see the state before deletion.

Comment: If you manually run `DELETE FROM my_employee WHERE LAST_NAME LIKE '%man%'`, does it delete the row?

Comment: yeah manually it deletes the row mentioned above and then I reinserted the same row manually and after this I used java code to delete the same  row and then did "select * from table " statement  manually and guess what ..the same row is still there

Comment: auto-commit is true by default

Comment: And other updates like changing values of a specified row is working when using JDBC.Insert commands, Update commands , creating a new table working properly  in JDBC but not delete statement.

Comment: Most probable explanation of this *mystery*. 1) insert row in SQL Developer, do NOT commit. 2) Test delete in JDBC session - does not work!  3) Query in Developer - you see data! 4) delete in SQL Developer works. Moral of the story - *do no switch between sessions while testing DML*.

Comment: Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver") has been unnecessary since Java 6. Everyone, please stop using it. "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" has been obsolete since Oracle 9.

Comment: what to do now?Still not working!!